# Rails HTTP Streaming: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `encoding' for #<ActionView::StreamingBuffer>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, unicorn, slim-lang, http-streaming

I try enabling HTTP streaming in my Rails app but I keep having this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `encoding' for #<ActionView::StreamingBuffer:0x007ffad89dae38>):
    1: = content_for :content do
    2:   h1 Hello
    3: 
    4: = render template: 'layouts/application'
```

And it seems to work fine without the `content_for` (or `provide` method).

My situation is: I have a controller with an action using `render stream: true`, this action renders the `normal` template that will call the `application` template.

I tried with a lot of different servers (WEBrick, Puma, Unicorn, ...) but the issue is the same.

My templating format is `slim`.

Comment: I just encountered a similar problem.